# Solving general cubic via radicals

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let us consider the general cubic polynomial $x^{3} + ax^{2} + bx + c$ over $\mathbb{Q}(a, b, c)$. It is possible to find explicit expression of the roots, say $p, q, r$ in terms of $a, b, c$ via Cardano's method. The roots are then expressed as nested radical expression made up of $a, b, c$. Moreover in order to obtain the expression for all roots $p, q, r$ it is necessary to use the cubic roots of unity which lie outside $\mathbb{Q}$.

> Does that mean that the cubic equation can not be solved using radicals if we restrict all the radicals extensions to lie somewhere between the inclusion $F = \mathbb{Q}(a, b, c)\subset K = \mathbb{Q}(p, q, r)$? If yes then how does this work out in Galois theory? Is the corresponding Galois group not-solvable?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but in the celebrated *casus irreducibilis" (an irreducible cubic over $\Bbb Q$ with three real roots) the equation is insoluble if you only allow real radicals.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: The question is not about casus irreducibilis, but rather it is about the general cubic with literal coefficients so that $a, b, c$ here are indeterminates and cubic is considered as a polynomial over field $F = \mathbb{Q}(a, b, c)$ (field of rational functions of $a, b, c$ with rational coefficients. The splitting field is clearly $K = \mathbb{Q}(p, q, r)$. In short $K$ is the field of all rational functions of $p, q, r$ with rational coefficients and $F$ is the set of all symmetric rational functions of $p,q, r$ with rational coefficients. contd..

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: The solution by Cardano uses radicals which don't lie in $K$.

Comment: Then I suspect the same argument as used in the casus irreducibilis will apply here too.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Ok it appears I have got the issue clarified by myself after looking at link between solvable groups and radical extensions. The Galois group $\textrm{Gal}(K/F)$ here is $S_{3}$ which is solvable, but this does not mean that $K\supset F$ is a radical extension. It only means that there is some radical extension $L \supset F$ such that $L \supset K \supset F$. In the current case $L = K(e^{2\pi i/3})$. I was under the impression that if $\textrm{Gal}(K/F)$ is solvable then $K\supset F$ is radical extension.

Comment: @user1952009: It is good to use braces in TeX whenever there is a syntax for them. Thus if the exponent consists of a single letter then it is fine without braces, but suppose i want to change it to something with 2 letters then i will need to add braces. Thus by habit I use braces everywhere.

Comment: @user1952009: $a, b, c$ are transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @user1952009: I fixed your typo. It was not a casual edit to add brace. You wrote $\phi(p)$ instead of $\phi(p^{n})$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57446/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-user1952009).

Comment: @user1952009: the field of roots is always an extension of field of coefficients. Clearly we can see that $a = -(p + q + r), b = pq + qr + rp, c = -pqr$ so it is evident that $\mathbb{Q}(a, b, c)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(p, q, r)$.

Comment: Yes obviously, so you want to look at $K = \mathbb{Q}(p,q,r), F = \mathbb{Q}(p+q+r,pq+pr+qr, pqr)$ and the Galois group of $K/F$.  Is it a finite extension, what are the minimal polynomials ?

Comment: @user1952009: yes thats what I was trying to do and I also understood that the group is $S_{3}$ symmetric group on 3 symbols. i did not evaluate minimal polynomials, rather I used the fact that since $p, q, r$ are also transcendental here, any permutation of the roots will fix the field generated by $a, b, c$ (because these are symmetric polynomials in roots $p, q, r$) and hence all the permutations must be in the galois group

Comment: Why don't you start with $x^3+ax+b$ ? And I don't understand "lie between $F$ and $K$". It seems what's on [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9thode_de_Cardan#Formules_de_Cardan) says that $K/F$ is a radical extension, and we can easily find the minimal polynomials and Galois group. What do you want more ?

Comment: @user1952009: You should check my previous comments (replies to user LordSharktheUnknown). this issue is sorted out and there is nothing more needed. I was having a misconception about radical extensions and their link with solvable galois groups.

Comment: So the question is solved, right ? Now what I don't understand really is how it works in degree $5$ or more. If the coefficients are $A = a_1,\ldots, a_5$, we have $K= F(h_1(A),\ldots,h_5(A))$ where $h_k$ are "inverse algebraic" functions, which means they are analytic except at some branch points, but we don't have a closed-form in term of $\sqrt[?]{..}\ $ ?